# Making a java custom control accessible in Eclipse WindowsBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar

This is driving me nuts. Please help.

In Java, I've created a custom user control. It's a JPanel that contains a label, a text field, and a button. I'm using Eclipse to do all of this. I'm also using WindowBuilder to drag and drop GUI elements onto my custom control.

I want other applications to have access to this control from WindowBuilder.

How do I add this custom control to Windows Builder in a category that I created?

In .Net, I would tell the Design view to reference the compiled DLL of a user control that I'd created. I'd think that it would be the same for WindowBuilder / Java.

If it helps, this is the code for my control.

```
package net.UserControl;

import javax.swing.*;

/* several java.swing imports here */


public class UserControl  extends JPanel
{
private JTextField txtfTextField;
private JLabel lblTestLabel;


public UserControl(String greeting) 
{
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    lblTestLabel = new JLabel("This textbox will greet you.");
    lblTestLabel.setBounds(113, 12, 192, 15);
    lblTestLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    this.add(lblTestLabel);

    txtfTextField = new JTextField();
    txtfTextField.setBounds(66, 37, 303, 81);
    txtfTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    this.add(txtfTextField);
    txtfTextField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnOkButton = new JButton("OK");
    btnOkButton.setBounds(184, 130, 54, 25);
    this.add(btnOkButton);

    btnOkButton.addActionListener(new OkButtonClickManager());
    txtfTextField.setText(greeting); 

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);        
}

private static class OkButtonClickManager implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}//end ClickManager

}//end userControl
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is likely that you will need to provide a default/empty constructor

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article, it will help you.
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/NewComponentsTutorial.pdf

In our project, there are lots of custom SWT components which are shared in a custom_pallet.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<commands>

<addCategory
    id="bbs.rcpkit.layout.components"
    name="BBS RCPKit Layouts"
    description="layout components"
    visible="true"
    open="true"/>

<addFactory
    id="bbs.rcpkit.layout.components.palette"
    name="Equal Width Grid"
    description="createGrid():"
    visible="true"
    class="jp.co.bbs.bizwork.eclipse.swt.widgets.WidgetFactory"
    signature="createGrid()"
    static="true"
    category="bbs.rcpkit.layout.components"/>
</command>
```

You can define constructor as fine as factory method, and you can also add some annotation to instruct WindowBuilder Pro to parse your component correctly with initial settings.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/DesignerCustomizationAPI.pdf